# Why doesn't my variable defined in Config.groovy appear in the grailsApplication.config object in a .gsp page?

Tags: grails

I'm working on a Grails 2.4.2 application that is already in production. I need to find a way of dynamically choosing a logo image in a GSP page. The current page has it hard coded like this:

```
<div id="logo">
  <img src="/${grailsApplication.metadata['app.name']}/images/logo.png" />
</div>
```

So I thought that if I declared the name of the image as a variable 'logoName' in the **Config.groovy** file, I could reference it like this:

```
<div id="logo">
  <img src="/${grailsApplication.metadata['app.name']}/images/${grailsApplication.config.getProperty('logoName')}" />
</div>
```

However, this doesn't work. If I just print out the value of the ConfigSlurper object in the page, it contains a whole slew of key/value pairs, but NOT my variable. There's nothing magic about the Config.groovy file, and my variable is simply declared like:

```
logoName = 'foo.png'
```

I'm starting the app with:

```
grails RunApp
```

I've also tried different variations on the syntax for accessing the variable/property, but to no avail. Like:

```
<div id="logo"><img src="/${grailsApplication.metadata['app.name']}/images/${grailsApplication.config.logoName}" />
```

and

```
<div id="logo"><img src="/${grailsApplication.metadata['app.name']}/images/${grailsApplication.config.['logoName']}" />
```

This is driving me nuts. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is officially bizarre. Must have been a caching issue. After cleaning the project and rebuilding everything, it works as expected. Oh well. Case closed.

Comment: The Grails dev mantra: if something weird happens always do a clean (and clean-all)...